# error al cargar un txt en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a txt file with the bulk insert in sql statement it migrated to a table
I'm doing well, but when the txt is too large, given the failure to execute the batch. Error message: There was an exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Comment: `System.OutOfMemoryException` seems like a `.NET` exception. Where/How are you running this?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest separating your large text file into multiple smaller files.  Try cutting it in half, and attempt again. If that doesn't work, cut it into 3, and so on.

It's not clear whether this is a one-off, or a repeated automated process.

Comment: is a process that takes place every 15 days, you can not split the file.
there is another solution

Comment: I have way to limit the number of rows that I inserted with a bulk